# File gets corrupted when transferring it via socket

Tags: java, c++, sockets, boost-asio

My Java client sends a file to a C++ server using this code:

```
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(path);
byte[] buffer = new byte[64*1024];
int bytesRead = 0;

while ( (bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer)) != -1)
{
     if (bytesRead > 0)
     {   
           this.outToServer.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
     }   
}
```

My C++ server receives the bytes using this code:

```
vector<char> buf5(file_length);
size_t read_bytes;
do
{
    read_bytes = socket.read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buf5,file_length));
    file_length -= read_bytes;
}
while(read_bytes != 0);
string file(buf5.begin(), buf5.end());
```

And then creates the file using this code:

```
ofstream out_file( (some_path).c_str() );
out_file << file << endl;
out_file.close();
```

However, somehow the file gets corrupted during this process.

 At the end of the process, both files(the one sent and the one created) have the same size.

What am I doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated!

Edit: tried to use different code for receiving the file, same result:

```
char buf[file_length];
    size_t length = 0;
while( length < file_length )
{
    length += socket.read_some(boost::asio::buffer(&buf[length], file_length - length), error);
}
string file(buf);
```

Comment: what do you mean by corrupted?

Comment: I'm sending a .so file. When I try to open it using "dlopen", it produces an error. "dlopen" works fine on the original file.

Comment: Have never had experience with `boost::asio`, but the way how you create the buffer object over the same vector in every iteration seems suspicious. Are you sure that every read does not reuse the beginning of the buffer, the remainder remaining unused?

Comment: Try to run md5sum on both files. Is it the same?

Comment: where do you obtain `file_length` in your first example or `config_file_length` in the second example?

Comment: @AndreyChernyakhovskiy look at the edit

Comment: Check if they're the same size. Make sure you're writing using binary and not ascii mode.

Comment: @Narkha edited the last code a bit... I sent it before sending the file. the file_length received is correct, and the server reads file_length amount of bytes

Comment: @user130955 Yes, but how much do you *save in the output file*? I bet it's not the same, due to your using `string` and `<<` for binary data.

Comment: @user130955, this way it seems reasonable as to how you read the data into the buffer. But when you contruct a `string` from that buffer, the constructor will stop at the first zero byte it encounters; you should also pass the length. The question is, why do you need the string at all?

Comment: @AndreyChernyakhovskiy Actually I don't. I used the string to write to the file using "<<" operator, which apparently was a mistake. Anyway, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) is it a text file?
2) if not try opening the file in binary mode before writing, also do not use << operator, instead use write or put methods

Comment: +1 For completeness, OP should use a function that fulfills [UnformattedOutputFunction](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/UnformattedOutputFunction) concept.

Comment: Thanks. Opened the file in binary mode and used "write" function, and it did the job.

Answer (score 0):

In your first example the problem appears to be this line:

```
read_bytes = socket.read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buf5,file_length));
```

This results in you overwriting the first N bytes of your string and not appending multiple reads correctly.

In your second example the problem is likely:

```
 string file(buf);
```

If `buf` contains any NUL characters then the string will be truncated. Use the same string creation as in your first example with a `std::vector<char>`.

If you still have problems I would recommend doing a binary diff of the source and copied files (most hex editors can do this). This should give you a better picture of exactly where the difference is and what may be causing it.

Comment: I wish I had 15 rep to vote up. I used the second example and Tejas answer and that did the job. Thank you!